# Ubuntu 16.04 bad resolution and laggy

Tags: 16.04, graphics, display-resolution

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell PowerEdge R630, and I am stuck at 640x480 resolution and mouse movements/key entries are laggy.

It says the graphics are gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe.

It's getting to the point where it is almost unusable, does anyone have any advice?

EDIT:  `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` output:

```
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2 (rev 01)
   DeviceName: Embedded Video
   Subsystem: Dell G200eR2
```

EDIT 2: `lspci -k | grep VGA -A3` output:

```
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2 (rev 01)
   DeviceName: Embedded Video
   Subsystem: Dell G200eR2
7f:08:0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done hopefully it helps!

Comment: Hm, no kernel module. Can you run `lspci -k | grep VGA -A3`?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1316035

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6, that's rather confusing though aha i'll look for a solution in all those comments

Comment: I tried the solution in the comments and it stopped the server from booting, guess I better look at returning it.